# Obsolete references to the FAQ

Tags: discussion

In a [recently closed question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18316/which-other-schengen-countries-should-i-visit-from-munich-such-that-the-cost-is), it says

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
>   specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate,
>   arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this
>   question can be improved and possibly reopened, [see the FAQ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#close) for
>   guidance.

Which has a link to https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#close

But the FAQ doesn't exist any more - https://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#close redirects to https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions , which is part of the "Help Center".

Comment: Where has it gone?

Comment: At lease it still jumps to the appropriate section in the help center - better than a broken link :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Introducing a brand new, consolidated Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182812/164542) is the relevant Meta StackOverflow post. StackExchange thought this would be the best way of consolidating all the help information. The FAQ is now at Travel's "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"